# for each row of a matrix copy its values to a separate list

Tags: python

I am new to Python and want to resolve WITHOUT NUMPY this case:
A script/function that take matrix[x][y] and generate/return x lists l1,l2,...lx each of them with y elements. 
For example:

```
matrix=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
```

Expected result:

```
l1=[1,2,3] l2=[4,5,6] l3=[7,8,9] l4=[10,11,12]
```

Comment: If your matrix is a list of lists as you signalized, you can access the i-th row by matrix[i]. Did you try using that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: Since a variable number of variables can be created, how are you going to write code that references only the ones created?

Comment: You have already achieved what you are trying to create: you have `x` lists, each of them with `y` elements, and they are already packed neatly inside a list. You can access each one of them with indexing. Why complicate with separated variables?

Comment: @Tomerikoo that was the assignment....;-)

Comment: Sorry to say then, but that shows something about the person who gave this assignment. It is not very practical to base data access upon variable names. How can you know whether there are 3, 5, or 10 lists to look for? This is what data-structures are for ;-)

Comment: Even me, as novice, have to agree you are right....

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a dictionary, where keys are row indeces and values are rows:

```
rows={}
for i,r in enumerate(matrix):
    rows[i] = r  

rows
{0: [1, 2, 3], 
 1: [4, 5, 6], 
 2: [7, 8, 9], 
 3: [10, 11, 12]}
```

In this way you can access the `i-th` row by `rows[i]` (remark index starts from 0)

To generate your expected output:

```
for i,r in enumerate(matrix):
    globals()[f'l{i+1}'] = r
```

Comment: Is it possible to generate separate lists as I asked? If yes how can than be accessed if their name would be in form l1, l2, l3,....ln?

Comment: Edited my answer, in this way you create variables dynamically in the for loop

Comment: I hope you realize that your dictionary achieves nothing over using the original matrix except creating a memory overhead. A dict with index keys is basically a list, which is how the data is already input

Comment: The OP asked to access each element by a specific name, a dictionary gives you this freedom, I am aware that it is creating memory overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `locals()` or `globals()`, they will help you to create variables so try this:

```py
for idx, value in enumerate(matrix):
    locals()['l%d'%(idx+1)] = value
```

Comment: THe [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) for `locals()` clearly states that the returned dictionary should not be modified.

Comment: Same comment as for @FBruzzesi

Comment: Sure! It will help you to generate variables as you asked but you can't modify them. Anyway this way satisfies your request I think so.
Just try `print(l1)`

Comment: 1-does not understand what's the role of modulo (%) operator in  `['l%d'%(idx+1)]` 2-how do I call all variables(l1,l2,...lx) in a for loop ? I tried `for x in range(len(matrix)) print(lx)` but didn't work

Comment: 1. It just help you name your variable. `%d` helps you pass digit param to your string.
2. You have already assigned a matrix item to your variable names so if you want to print them out. try this `for idx in range(len(matrix)) print(locals()['l%d'%(idx+1)])`

Comment: Got it! Thank you!